# Angular Dynamic [*ngModel)] for List of Inputs

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a list of inputs with dynamic model but unfortunately, I get stuck on how I can implement this properly.

Basically, I have sample `.ts` here. array of object has initial object which is the apple.

```
fruits: any[] = [
    {
        name1: 'Apple'
    }
]
```

In my UI, I created something like this one:

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fruit.name[i]" />
</div>
    <button (click)="addNewInput()">Add new fruit</button>
```

When the user clicks the `addNewInput()` button, then it should automatically add a new input.

But I'm getting an error that says, `0 is undefined`

any help for this or alternative way to do this?

Here is the StackBlitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbkzjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: can you share the code in https://stackblitz.com/ so that it will easier to understand and help

Comment: I added the link @a.prakash

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1gpzfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access fruits['name'][0] -> this is not the same as fruits['name0'].

Given you are using *ngFor you shouldn't need to use the index position as well.

```
fruits: any[] = [
    { name: 'Apple' },
    { name: 'Pear' }
]
```

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i = index">
    <input type="text" [name]="'fruit' + i" [(ngModel)]="fruit.name" />
</div>
<button (click)="addNewInput()">Add new fruit</button>
```

You will have to add a name that is different for each input though, i have used the index for this purpose.

Comment: But how can I get the name and it's certain data in the `.ts` file?

Comment: You want to access the values entered in the form from the ts file? [(ngModel)] is two way data binding, so any changes made on the inputs would be reflected in the fruits array.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I mean, the data under the specific `[name]` since the `[name]` holds the id of a unique input because of it's index

Comment: You can use filter/find over fruits on the basis of unique attribute (i.e name or id) in ts

Comment: You can also just access the array directly passing a positional argument. `this.fruits[i]`

Comment: Have not faced same issue but found good solution